# Connect to visualstudio.com repository without clone all files

Tags: git, visual-studio, repository

I have a large project with about more than 5 gig.

now I want continue the project with another computer.

Is there any way in visual studio that just copy the file (for example by usb flash) and do not wait to clone all file from repository by internet.

** I did it by add the solution on local repository and connect to visualstudio.com repository but it needs fetch before using (and it seems it is try to download all the files and I do not want this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can copy just the folder and it's going to be enough. Be aware of any absolute paths in your solution though (you didn't mentioned what you have ont he repo).

The other option, provided that you already sent the repo to visualstudio.com, is to do a shallow clone, in which case you will locally get only the last `n` commits, and of course a fully working git repository.

Comment: thanks after some try it works.first copy file from computer1 to computer2 then add local git repo of that folder then connect to remote repo and use sync.(I dont khow why but some times it takes too long)

Comment: Hum. It probably did communicate all data... But if it worked, then great!